# Paperspace gradient remote jupyter kernel

Tags: python

I am using Paperspace gradient service, and i connected to remote jupyter kernel using vs code, how to be able to work on my local directory while connecting to the remote kernel

i tried this code

```
import os
os.getcwd()
```

and i got /notebooks'

Comment: This is roughly comparable to asking how you can get your outsourced employee in another country to interact with the contents of your living room. You might be able to upload your files to the remote machine and work with them there, but you're not going to be able to get the remote kernel to interact directly with your local filesystem.